# How to look up and switch to a pty or pid within tmux?

Tags: tmux

I have this shell script to figure out from a pid or a tty which tmux window that is:

```bash
#!/bin/sh
if [ -c "$1" ]; then
    tty="$1"
else
    tty=/dev/$(ps -q "$1" -otty=)
fi
target=$(tmux list-panes -aF '#{pane_tty} #S:#I' | sed -ne "s~$tty \(.*\)~\1~p")
echo "$target"
```

(error handling deleted for clarity)

And from that, just for fun, I can set up a copy-mode key binding like:

```
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi C-] switch-client -t'#(my_script.sh "#{copy_cursor_word}")'
```

So when I try to edit a file and vim brings up its "this file is already open" message, I can cursor to the PID and hit ^] to jump straight to the already-open editor.

But *should* I need to go via an external script to implement this, or is it something that can be implemented entirely within tmux?

Comment: It seems something like `bind-key -T copy-mode-vi C-] switch-client -t#{S:#{W:#{P:#{?#{==:#{pane_tty},/dev/#(ps -q #{copy_cursor_word} -otty=)},#S#I,}}}}` is nearly the answer but evidently not quite the answer.

Actually, I see why not.  #() returns old results from the command, whereas this really needs the immediate response.  So that's not a good way to look up the string (and doing it in a loop would be even less efficient).